# Transferring microsoft OEM, FPP and VLSC license

Tags: windows, license, oem

We had purchased Microsoft licenses like OS, Office, Visual Studio, SQL server etc. from the local reseller. Some of them are OEM, FPP and also some are Open Licenses purchased through Volume Licensing Service Center.

All the above said licenses were purchased in the name of company1. 
Now, my companies whole business has been acquired by another company called company2.

But, all the software and hardware resources remain same. So, now all the licenses were purchased in the name of company1 to be transferred to company2.

I found that Open Licenses can be transferred by filling up this [form](http://www.microsoftvolumelicensing.com/Downloader.aspx?DocumentId=8396) and submit to Microsoft.

But, what about OEM and FPP products? What is the procedure for the same?

Even Microsoft support people does not know what is the procedure. Does anyone know?

Please help

Comment: OEM licenses are tied to the machine.  FPP are physical licenses, they can be transferred or sold again.  In the case of FPP you also might look how often they can be transferred.  Check the terms of the license for that information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a reply from Microsoft that it is possible to transfer all kind of licenses. We need to fill this [form](http://www.microsoftvolumelicensing.com/Downloader.aspx?DocumentId=8396) and send to Microsoft if license is Perpetual. For Non - Perpetual Licenses we need to directly contact our  reseller/retailer.